# Asp.Net Core + Angular SPA + on premise ADFS cross origin request to ADFS triggered from client blocks UI

Tags: c#, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0, adfs3.0

I have set up on premise ADFS authentication on my Asp.net Core + Angular 5 Single page application. The authentication is done on the level of Asp.Net on Web API and MVC controllers. Angular 5 application is embedded in index.cshtml.

Authentication works perfectly fine for login and logout.
But when the user is browsing through the application a preflight request is triggered from browser to ADFS, which blocks the post request made during that time. Below is the error that I am getting on browser console

> Failed to load https://adfsxxxxxxxxxx/adfs/ls/?>wtrealm=xxxxx&wa=wsignin1.0&wreply=xxxxx%2Fsignin->wsfed&wctx=CfDJ8Nyz41BVvQdBop5lee2HgGltVBEO-JXsCDT0Mbjno6BPcJNI1pFe->mlNy0xonxmZzyhK1LGUKcaniahjJ6vDG3UQ-hdBf3XMQQF16cyXPglxcG6->d1mHw1osMS77_pdCYMFT57iOcgCZ9x3hwjt6e_FzyXuOMeRhtzp_UB87m82OvvtZaqgj2Xvcic->YuhwocmpzK73hpx-yk4sG7zCyDqDCEA_Ixel7EMwOx8NQc7OBPBWPtsPAIdGtag4OosgdZ->9tod_zKvV_rfhTtO-cdSQr002HvTPuLwktLw1t3-7-: Response to preflight request >doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is >present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://xxxxxx' is therefore not >allowed access.

Please let me know if there is a solution for this. Thanks.

Below is the code for setting up ADFS Authentication in StartUp.cs file.

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddWsFederation(options =>
        {
            options.Wtrealm = Configuration["wsfed:realm"];
            options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["wsfed:metadata"];
        }).AddCookie(cookieoption =>
        {
            cookieoption.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            cookieoption.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, preflight request is failing due to origin access control policy. You need to enable/set Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) policy.

1.Create CORS policy using `AddCors` method in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Cors
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("MyPolicy"));
        });

        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```

2.Enable CORS policy using `UseCors` in Startup.Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Enable Cors
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I highly suggest you to understand CORS and also refer to [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I’ve set up CORS already. But still it’s not working. I’m getting http status 302 for web api method call. Then a get request to ADFS is automatically triggered which is causing the issue. Any idea why 302 is returned ?

Comment: Setting up CORS doesn't seem to work for single-page-apps at all.